# How to set the origin of two axes on the same level

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I cannot solve my problem. I am using matplotlib and I am plotting histogram and theoretical pdf, but I am not able to set the 0 values on both y-axes on the same level. 
This is my code and the plot I get:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, pdf_g, label="Norm") 
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.hist(df['col'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `ax1.hist(df['col'])`?

Comment: Because of the scale. pdf_g gives probabilities which are at most around 0.4 and histogram has values over 5000

Comment: Oh, I see. Then change the lower limit of ax1 `ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0)`?

Comment: It was pertaining y-axis, but it solved the problem. I tried before but this time it worked. Thanks!